# Delete message history of a User, after the user left the server Discord.Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_member_leave(member: discord.Member):
    for message in client.text_channels:
        if message.author == member:
            await message.delete()
```

Thats what I have so far, but it isn't really working.
I have no idea how to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to ban them and immediately unban them, clearing all of their messages.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member: discord.Member):
  await member.ban()
  await member.unban()
```

Comment: The problem is, it will also unban banned users, so is there a way to get around this?

Comment: If you want to permanently ban them when they leave, then just remove the `await member.unban()`

Comment: @Tommy you could also put it into a command and just use the command on someone to clear their messages